# Primefaces poll stops working when the server sends an empty response

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use the poll component from Primefaces 4.0 to make a request to the server every 10 minutes. Everything works just fine most of the time, but every now and then, I don't know why, the server returns an empty response with a 200 code (OK). This is a 100% empty response. A 0 bytes length response. So the `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse` method gets a `null` value as parameter, and when it tries to access the `documentElement` property of this object, I get an error *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property documentElement of null"* and everything stops working.

I don't know why I get empty responses, maybe its a problem in the network, or maybe it's a problem with the cluster in which the app is running, or maybe is the proxy; but the sysadmin doesn't care a lot about it, and so, I need to find a software solution.

Is there anything I can do which doesn't involve editing Primefaces' own files?

Thank you very much for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is wondering, I ended overwriting `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse`, checking whether the response is empty and calling the original method if everything is right

```
OriginalAjaxResponse = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse;

PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse = function (responseXML) {
    if (responseXML != null)
        OriginalAjaxResponse(responseXML);
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works

Comment: Is this workaround necessary for PrimeFaces 5.3.x and 6.0.x?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem yesterday and i find this blogpost which tells us to move h:outputStylesheet and h:outputScript to end of body.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="primefaces.locales.js"/>
```

http://maxyermayank.blogspot.com.tr/2013/10/jsf-ajax-response-returning-empty.html?showComment=1454339705279